# Invalid Pointer Error in AXML files

Tags: android, mono, visual-studio-2013

I installed Mono for android in my visual studio and I can compile my android application well; but ***I can't open `AXML` files with android designer***. I can see just its XML format.

The error is:

`The operation could not be completed. Invalid Pointer.`

I uninstalled it and installed again; but didn't work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the this is due to android SDK. Try to update your android SDK Tools.